# How to count the number of trues in an array of boolean values?

Tags: javascript

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  let sum = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfSheep[i] == true) {
      sum[i].push(arrayOfSheep[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum.length;
}
var array1 = [
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
];
console.log(countSheeps(array1));
```

I'm having trouble counting the number of trues in an array of boolean values. I was expecting counting value must be 17 but it's 0, can anyone please tell me where I am wrong and what I should do to make it work?

Comment: Push into sum not sum[i]. `sum.push(arrayOfSheep[i]);`

Comment: .length instead of .lenght

Comment: And you spelled `length` incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` is an easy way to count items in an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

One version of it takes two parameters: a function, and the initial value of the *accumulator*.

The function parameter also has two parameters: the current *accumulator* and an item from the array. It will call this function for every item in the array. The return value will be passed as the *accumulator* of the next call.

The ternary statement `sheep ? acc+1 : acc` means if `sheep` is truthy, return `acc+1` else  return `acc`. The return is implicit when declaring an arrow function with no curly braces.

```js
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  return arrayOfSheep.reduce((acc, sheep) => sheep ? acc+1 : acc, 0)
}

const array1 = [
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
];

console.log(countSheeps(array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be `arrayOfSheep.length`, not `arrayOfSheep.lenght`.
2. You need to push to `sum` array,`sum.push(arrayOfSheep[i])`.

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  let sum = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++) {
      if (arrayOfSheep[i]) {
        sum.push(arrayOfSheep[i]);
      }
    }
  return sum.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner: filter the array and then take the length:

```js
const array1 = [ true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true,];

console.log(array1.filter(Boolean).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to filter and length that result.
Use const instead of var, Cause the value doesn't change in this situation.

```
const array1 = [
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
];

console.log(array1.filter(item => item).length);
```